# Issue with masking using Open GL 1.0 stencil buffer in iOs

Tags: ios, opengl-es, stencil-buffer

I have been struggling to find a solution for a simple masking using Stencil Buffer in OPEN GL 1.0 on the iOs.

I draw the background and then I draw on top of it using glPushMatrix a frame which is drawn using drawFrame.

My frame is made of a VideoFrameTexture which I try to mask using maskTexture using the stencil buffer. My objective is to draw only part of the videoFrameTexture (which is defined by the white area of my mask and which corresponds to a circle shape) onto the background.

I use the following code but the mask image is not taken into account. It's a Black an white png.

```
-(void) drawFrame{

GLfloat vertexes[] =
{
    -1.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};
GLshort texes[] = {
    1, 1,
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
};

glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexes);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, texes);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);


glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);

glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xffffffff);  


/// Mask Drawing
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, maskTexture);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xffffffff); /* draw if ==1 */
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);


///Frame Drawing
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, videoFrameTexture);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);


glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


glDeleteTextures(1, &videoFrameTexture);

}
```

I draw my view using the following code:

```
- (void) drawView
{
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
//glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT| GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

   glOrthof(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -10.0f, 10.0f);
   glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glPushMatrix();
glScalef(1, 0.75, 1);
glTranslatef(0, -1, 0);
glRotatef(90, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
[self drawBackground];
glPopMatrix();

 glPushMatrix();

glScalef(1, 1, 1);
glTranslatef(0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(90, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
[self drawFrame];
glPopMatrix();

//present frame buffer
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stencil buffer is not available for 1.0. Only 2.0

Comment: What? ES 1.0 doesn't have a stencil buffer? really? I looked into the spec and it indeed says an implementation is not required to include a depth or stencil buffer (though it can and the stencil operations are supported). Great so you don't even need to have depth buffer in ES 1.0, amazing!

Comment: @ChristianRau: This is simply not true (at least not for v1.1), I just got stencil shadows working on OpenGL ES 1.1/iOS.